# Unity: fixed Y axis of prefabs

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am building a top down shooter using the unity survival shooter assets. The problem I face is that all of the spawnable prefabs(enemy, player) have a fixed Y axis position. This is sometimes causing them to float in places where the ground level is low and sometimes they will sink where the ground level is higher. They do not change or update the Y axis as the terrain does.

How can I fix this so that the prefabs move according to the terrain.

**Enemy Settings**

[image]

**PlayerSettings**

[image]

**Scene Screenshot**
[image]

**Terrain Navmesh**
[image]

Comment: Can you show a screenshot of the scene with the player and enemy objects not matching the terrain? The enemy I can perhaps attribute to a poorly-matching navmesh, but the player it seems is using strictly physics for movement, so I don't see why the player would fail to adhere to the terrain.

Comment: updated with the scene view !

Comment: You may have to add your scene view back in at the bottom since I fixed the grammar.

Comment: Thank you for the response, I added it again

Comment: any suggestions @Serlite ?

Comment: Hmm, it's still not really clear what your problem might be. (I'm honestly having a difficult time discerning it from the screenshot you provided...) Can you show us how your navmesh looks relative to the terrain?

Comment: Navmeshes on terrains are difficult, especially when they are extremely unique terrains with lots of facets. Can you place a plane underneath the terrain that encompases the entire width and length and add the navmesh to the plane. Then put your terrain on top of it?

Comment: I just found this, here's something to try https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/simple-terrain-navmesh-setup.252161/

Comment: Updated with terrain navmesh. The terarin is a prefab cliff

Answer (score 0):

I would recomand you read this: http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/197952/rigid-body-and-character-controller.html if this doesn't solve your problem,
first I would try to play around with the mass and angular drag. Second of all I would rebake the nav Mesh. Third I would change the slope limit and step height and rebake again. And last I would try to use agent.updateposition = true; and agent.updateRotation = true;

I hope at least one worked. Happy coding !

Comment: Fixed it by adding navmesh agent which was missing from the prefabs